# Is someone trying to connect to my VPS?

Tags: debian, sshd, vps

When I make the command `journalctl -xe` on my VPS (Debian 9) host by OVH, I see several attempts to connect, is this normal?

Here is a small part of the logs:

```
-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-04-08 22:51:43 CEST, end at Tue 2019-04-09 09:31:32 CE
ST. --
Apr 09 08:01:49 vps668970 sshd[4559]: Disconnected from 173.249.50.217 port 4333
8 [preauth]
Apr 09 08:02:21 vps668970 sshd[4561]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authenticatio
n failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=173.249.50.217  user=root

Apr 09 08:02:23 vps668970 sshd[4561]: Failed password for root from 173.249.50.2
17 port 34630 ssh2
Apr 09 08:02:23 vps668970 sshd[4561]: Received disconnect from 173.249.50.217 po
rt 34630:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Apr 09 08:02:23 vps668970 sshd[4561]: Disconnected from 173.249.50.217 port 3463
0 [preauth]
Apr 09 08:02:54 vps668970 sshd[4563]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authenticatio
n failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=173.249.50.217  user=root

Apr 09 08:02:56 vps668970 sshd[4563]: Failed password for root from 173.249.50.2
17 port 54154 ssh2
Apr 09 08:02:56 vps668970 sshd[4563]: Received disconnect from 173.249.50.217 po
rt 54154:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Apr 09 08:02:56 vps668970 sshd[4563]: Disconnected from 173.249.50.217 port 5415
4 [preauth]
Apr 09 08:03:23 vps668970 kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens3 OUT= MAC=fa:16:3e:
```

Comment: Yes, bots probing SSH exposed to the internet is normal, but usually not desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal.

Read this interesting symantec article on "[Analyzing Malicious SSH Login Attempts](https://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/analyzing-malicious-ssh-login-attempts)".

---

Here is the top 20 of failed login account names and number of tries for my server since April, 1st:

```
   2919 root
    194 admin
    122 test
     83 zabbix
     67 user
     66 ftpuser
     65 postgres
     60 mysql
     58 nagios
     49 ubuntu
     44 www-data
     43 pi
     42 support
     42 oracle
     39 jboss
     36 guest
     34 usuario
     33 tomcat
     32 dell
     30 www
```

- 9872 total attempts with 2182 different account names.
- 0.8 attempts per minute.

`root` ssh login is disabled, the rest of all account names does not exist or has `/usr/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false` as shell. So nothing to worry about.

I have `fail2ban` installed to reduce the possible attempts per time, but as the attempts come from botnets with lots of IP addresses and `fail2ban` works on IP addresses it's not too effective.

Next possible option to reduce the number of attempts would be to change the `ssh` port.

---

Command to gather this information:

```
grep -ho 'Failed password for .*' /var/log/auth.log{,.1} \
  | awk '{if ($4=="invalid") { print $6 } else { print $4 } }' \
  | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n20
```

Comment: In the time of writing this, there have been 8 more `root` login attempts ;-)